# How to send and receive data beween two JSF pages

Tags: jsf

Please help me. I want to send and receive data between two jsf pages. I am from php background new to jsf. i know how to sent and receive data in php but dont know how it done in jsf.

Comment: what you tried? can you post your code?

Comment: i created a h:dataTable which is working fine. I added one option there for deleting object that is also working and i want to add one more option for view the object from that list. please tell me ho i view the object in another page